# Simple way to reveal brush strokes, such as in the example

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, image, video

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLvmXuInbHo

I do have access to After Effects, but I would prefer doing all my video editing etc. in blender. Is there a simple way?

Comment: do a search for "dynamic painting" or use curves, Read: [How Do I Create a self drawing 2D Shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68590/how-do-i-create-a-self-drawing-2d-shape/68594#68594) and [How to achieve animated handwriting with variable thickness?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/how-to-achieve-animated-handwriting-with-variable-thickness/48130#48130)

Comment: Related:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31281/create-a-linear-brush-stroke-with-weight-paint